# Recorrer una lista de palabras, devolver las palabras y a que familia pertenecen

Tags: bucle-for, cmd

Tengo un bucle FOR en CMD, que devuelve unas palabras, a su vez necesito que me devuelva un segundo valor relacionado con dichas palabras

```
for %x in (Manzana_Fruta Flan_poste) do echo %x:first es un %x:last
```

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Estoy probando estos 2 ejemplos, son funcionales pero liosos:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %i in (list.txt) do for %x in (%i*) do @echo %x /%j
```

7z1900-x64.exe /S
winrar-x64-61b1.exe /S

```
for %P in (7z_S k-lite_VERYSILENT) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %x in ("%P") do for %x in (%x*) do echo %x /%y
```

7z1900-x64.exe /S
K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1653_Basic.exe /VERYSILENT